# jQuery prevent submit of form inside of if statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, preventdefault

Sorry if there are some mistakes, but I am a total noob and I am also posting for the first time on StackOverflow.

I am trying to configure a submit form, that controls if the inserted PIN is right, and if so goes on with the submission. I did some online research and found out that with jQuery we can use to function `event.preventDefault()`, I tried to insert it inside my AJAX request but it looks like it doesn't stop the form from being saved.

The code looks like these:

```
function verifyOTP() {
    $(".error").html("").hide();
    $(".success").html("").hide();
    var otp = $("#contomovimentato").val();
    var PIN =  $("#PINvalue").val();
    var input = {
        "otp" : otp,
        "PIN" : PIN,
        "action" : "verify_otp"
    };
    if (otp != null) {
        $.ajax({
            url : 'm_ajaxpinr.php',
            type : 'GET',
            dataType : "json",
            data : input,
            success : function(response) {
                $("." + response.type).html(response.message)
                $("." + response.type).show();
                },
            error : function() {
                alert("ss");
            }
        });
    } else {
        $(".error").html('XPIN non valido.')
        $(".error").show();
        error : function(event) { event.preventDefault(); };
    }
 //if I insert "return false;" here the submit is always blocked
}
```

I checked on atom if the parenthesis are right and it looks like it is.
Any ideas how I should use the preventDefault()?
I also checked if the output of m_ajaxpinr.php is correct, and it is. I also tried like these but it still didn't work...

```
    if (otp != null) {
        $.ajax({
            url : 'm_ajaxpinr.php',
            type : 'GET',
            dataType : "json",
            data : input,
            success : function(response) {
                $("." + response.type).html(response.message)
                $("." + response.type).show();
        $("form").submit(function(event) {
                    if (response.type == 'success')
                {
                    alert(response.type);
                }
                else if (response.type == 'error') 
                {
                    alert(response.type);
                    event.preventDefault();
                }
                });
```

Comment: The `event` is not being passed to your function, so you cannot call `preventDefault()` on it. How you access the event depends on how the `verifyOTP()` function is called. Can you please add that logic to the question.

Comment: `return false` at the end, so it *is* always blocked, then in the `success:` (after validation) call `$("#your_form_id")[0].submit()` to submit the form after validation and bypass the jquery submit handler.

Comment: The issue is that the ajax call is asynchronous so when your code gets to the last line (your comment) the ajax call is still running - so you need to "continue" after the ajax call has completed.

Comment: I tried inserting "`$("'form_id")[0].submit();` after `$("." + response.type).show();` but now the form is always submitting, even with wrong PINS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as said in comment above ajax call is asynchronous, you need to complete cancel default action for the form or put `event.preventDefault();` on the top function, then submit it in success function if it valid otp.

`.val()` will not return `null`, it return `empty` if no input.

```js
$('#myForm').on('submit', verifyOTP);

function verifyOTP(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // note this
  
  $(".error").html("").hide();
  $(".success").html("").hide();
  var otp = $("#contomovimentato").val();
  var PIN = $("#PINvalue").val();
  var input = {
    "otp": otp,
    "PIN": PIN,
    "action": "verify_otp"
  };

  if (otp) { // mean not null, undefined, empty, false, 0
    $.ajax({
      //url: 'm_ajaxpinr.php',
      url: 'https://httpbin.org/anything/test',
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: "json",
      data: input,
      success: function(response) {
        $("." + response.type).html(response.message)
        $("." + response.type).show();
        if(response.args.otp == 1234){
           console.log('valid otp, continue submission')
           $('#myForm').off('submit'); // remove submit event
           $('#myForm').submit(); // then submit the form
        }
        else{
          console.log('invalid pin,\nvalid pin: 1234');
        }
      },
      error: function() {
        console.log("server error, submission cancelled");
      }
    });
  } else {
    $(".error").html('XPIN non valido.')
    $(".error").show();
    console.log("otp maybe empty, submission cancelled");
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myForm">
  <input id="contomovimentato">
  <button>submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you for the complete answer! Really nice, yeah I kinda understood the fact that ajax is asynchronous, but couldn't realize how to change the code in a way that it "waits" for the end of the ajax call. As soon as I am at the pc I'll give it a try. Ah yeah, out of curiosity, why is "e" the argument of `function verifyOTP` now? Is it so we can use "e" for the function `preventDefault()` ? Thank you again for the help.

Comment: you're welcome, `e` is parameter name no matter if it `e` or `event`. if solved please mark the answer as correct.